# Change cell colour depending on weekday

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that contains a header line on first row and a date field on first column. Is it possible to use conditional formatting to give a different colour to each cell on column A depending on its weekday? And I mean the weekday of the cell's value, not today's date.

Built-in rules work fine and I've already determined that `=WEEKDAY(A2, 2)=1` (`=DIASEM(A2; 2)==1` in my Spanish version) determines whether `A1` is monday (etc.) but I'm unable to create a custom rule that has any visible effect. I've tried as follows:

1. Select complete column A
2. At "Home/ Conditional Formatting/ New rule" select "Use a formula..."
3. Type `=WEEKDAY(****, 2)=1` where **** is every coordinate combination I've been able to think of: `A2:A9999`, `A`, `A2`... (no option makes sense for me because I want to refer to *current* cell)
4. Choose a format (a solid fill colour) and save

No matter what I do, all cells remain transparent. I understand I need 7 rules but I haven't made the first one work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below worked for me.

I did 3 rules to show you, but you can keep going.

1. Select entire range of data
2. First formula = `=WEEKDAY(A2,2)=1` *(leaving it as `A2` and not `$A$2` means it will refer to the current cell in the data range.)*
3. Choose color
4. Set `Stop If True`
5. Repeat for next day `=WEEKDAY(A2,2)=2`
6. Make sure to order by `=1`,`=2`, `=3` and set `Stop If True` for all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: About `A2`... Must I use the coordinate of the first cell in selection or the first cell that contains a date? Do I need to select just a limited set of rows rather than the complete column?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - select the range that **actually** has dates in it and just right the formulas as a relative references (no `$`) to the **first cell with a date**. If you are still stuck, please post a screenshot of your data, and I can help more.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working at last... It's so painful that Excel does not warn about almost any error! Just one more thing... Is there a way to extend these rules to all rows, or I need to make first a selection that goes to spreadsheet bottom side? I'll be adding rows every day.

Comment: Never mind, I guess I can edit the "Applies to" box.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - just select as many rows as you want the first time and it will apply to all those rows, whether or not there is data there or not. Or you can edit the `Applies To` area.